# Quick logic question about $P\leftrightarrow Q$, terminology

Tags: logic, terminology

I know that if we have $P\rightarrow Q$, $P$ can be called the antecedent and $Q$ the consequent or conclusion. If we have $P \leftrightarrow Q$, are there names for what we would call $P$ and $Q$ here?

I am writing a proof where I am proving $P \leftrightarrow Q$ and I already showed $P\rightarrow Q$ and I am trying to show $Q\rightarrow P$ but the statement of $Q$ is long and I was wondering if there is a word for $Q$ that I could use.

Comment: I don't think there's a word for it. In any case you can make it clear that you're proving $Q\to P$ and then you can simply call $Q$ the antecedent.

Comment: What about something along the lines of "To finish the proof, we must prove $Q\implies P$", and you could number this as (2). Then you could refer to the antecedent to (2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have displayed the claim
$$ P \iff Q$$
prominently, then you can subsequently call $P$ the "left hand side" and $Q$ the "right hand side".

Answer (score 1):

In some proofs of $P\Leftrightarrow Q$ statements, I've seen $P\Leftarrow Q$ referred to as "the sufficiency" and the other direction, "the necessity". This is rare as it can be misleading(#): there is no **the** in either direction (as the order is arbitrary).

I think the justification is in reading it left to right, as in, "you have $P$, is $Q$ necessary?" - sotospeak.

~

[(#) Just see my edit!]